# Webcam Capture only works sometimes

Tags: java, driver, webcam

I have a simple webcam program  in windows which works "occasionally" however most of the time it hangs while trying to find the default driver.

```
public class JavaApplication54 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(0);

    webcam.open();
    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));
    image = null;
    webcam.close();
}
```

}
The output I get is

```
13:22:08.910 [main] INFO  c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils -
    Searching driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.openimaj.OpenImajDriver
    13:22:08.915 [main] DEBUG c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils -
    Driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.openimaj.OpenImajDriver not found
    13:22:08.915 [main] INFO  c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils -
    Searching driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.civil.LtiCivilDriver
    13:22:08.915 [main] DEBUG c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils -
    Driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.civil.LtiCivilDriver not found
    13:22:08.915 [main] INFO  c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils -
    Searching driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.jmf.JmfDriver
    13:22:08.916 [main] DEBUG c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils -
    Driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.jmf.JmfDriver not found
    13:22:08.916 [main] INFO  com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - Webcam
    driver has not been found, default one will be used! 13:22:08.925
    [main] DEBUG c.g.s.w.d.b.WebcamDefaultDriver - Searching devices
```

Comment: I have just discovered that this seems to only happen when I run in Netbeans. If I run the JAR I get 100% success. So I guess the problem may lie with the way netbeans wraps the programs it runs. Anyone know how to cure this as it will make debugging a whole lot easier. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct this was one of the deadlock issues found in Webcam Capture API code. For details you can check these tickets available on the [Webcam Capture Github project](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) page: [#128](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/128), [#30](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/31)

I think the solution for you will be to use the newest version, which is (for the time when I'm writing this answer) [0.3.10-RC6](http://www.sarxos.pl/repo/maven2/com/github/sarxos/webcam-capture/0.3.10-RC6/webcam-capture-0.3.10-RC6-dist.zip). It should work regardless IDE (or CLI) used for development.